# Dynamic links in Twitter Bootstrap navbar in angularjs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I've created an angular application that uses Twitter bootstrap.

I would like dynamic links in the navbar (like `ng-href="#/{{course.id}}"`

They never render - they end up like `href="#/"`

If I put the navbar inside the `<div ng-view>` section of the page they do render, although I'd rather not put it there since I don't want to duplicate it on each partial.

*The basic page is laid out like this:*

```
<html ng-app="studentApp">
  <head> links to cdns here</head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">Dynamic bar here</div>
      <div ng-view>Partials in here</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For all partials that load in the ng-view portion, the interpolation happens as expected, but not in the navbar.

I created a Plunker rather than trying to include everything here. (http://plnkr.co/MK8QEDQUVawkOi92xJXk).

Comment: removing height:0 and overflow:hidden from .nav-collapse, .nav-collapse.collapse class shows the nav bar..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular will only work inside the ng-view once you start using routing.

I have only this in the containing page:

```
// links to cdn, js, css
<body>
  <div id="app-container" ng-app="dashboard" ng-view></div>
</body>
```

All the partials show up inside the div.

All partials include the navigation partial at the very top:

```
<div ng-include src="'html/navigation.html'"></div>
```

navigation.html has its own controller:

```
<div id="nav-bars-container" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
  <a href="#/{{course.id}}">Foo</a>
</div>
```

& thus has its own scope. Others can be injected:

```
function NavCtrl($scope, $route, $routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams);
  $scope.course.id = $routeParams.id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @flim. This is very helpful. I did not know about ng-include. The addition of the separate controller in the navbar helped me better understand controllers and routes. I've updated the plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/MK8QEDQUVawkOi92xJXk) with the changes (except the app location). The navbar picks up the routeParams and behaves like I want it to.  Per rajkamal I removed the responsive components from the style so the entire nav would render in the preview mode (rather than fullscreen), though it does wrap in a small width.

Comment: You're welcome! It was a brainteaser for me as well. Took me a bit to figure this pattern. I'm open to more elegant (DRY) solutions other than ng-include the navigation.html in all partials, but it is an easy solution.

Comment: For clarification (for me and future readers) you can't just use a partial view once and have it persist, it needs to be used on each page is that correct?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "have it persist."  You can wrap a `ng-if` or `ng-show` around the `<div ng-include..>` if you want the nav bar to show up conditionally.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean.. The nav bar needs to be included in each partial in this pattern. That's why I commented that I'm open to a more elegant solution that's as simple..